# IntelliJ compile multi-module project

Tags: build, compilation, intellij-idea

I changed my IDE from Eclipse to IDEA. I'm tring to configure it to work as effective as possible. I have following problem. I want IDEA to show me all files with compilation errors automatically after one file has been changed and causes the problem. I installed IntelliJ Eclipse Mode plugin and selected Eclipse compiler, but i have still following problem: In module-interfaces I have one interface - assume InterfaceA. Its implementation is contained in module-implementation1 *Implementation1* and in module-implementation2 *Implementation2* both depends on module-interfaces. Now when I change one interfaceA's method signature and save it, **make** is automatically triggered (eclipseMode plugin) but there is no compilation errors since in current module only interface resides. When I select all modules and select **make selected modules** compilation stops on the first module having errors i.e. module-implementation1 so I see only problem with *Implementation1*. Once I fix this implementation and start manually make process then IDE shows compilation error in *Implementation2*.

Is it possible to configure Intelij so that it compile all dependent modules and shows all files having compilation problems at all, as eclipse does?
Thanks in advance, it is really confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744303/intellij-idea-java-classes-not-auto-compiling-on-save). Basically, looks like it will be supported in IntelliJ 12

Comment: Hi @Vic thanks for the answer. Is it really not possible now to find out compilation error at once (not even manually)? How can you work then with such an IDE. Do you fix them step by step, starting make action after each fix? It seems weird.

Comment: @MarcinZasepa, in most cases your code is already compiling and you just refactor/add/remove some code. IntelliJ refactoring tools are great and they should break compilability. When you do break something up in the file you're currently editing, IntelliJ will alert you. And if it really bothers you so much, download 12 EAP version with the `Make Project AUtomatically` feature.

Comment: Actuall You are right, using Refactoring tools should do the thing, but it feels somehow strange not being sure if it actually compiles :) Thanks a lot for your help!