# IntelliJ IDEA "Make project automatically" woes

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jrebel

Back in December I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA but within a couple of days I switched back. Today I tried IntelliJ again and basically I have only one issue left.

The issue is I want to compile Java classes on saving. The reason is I'm using JRebel which will pick up the new class. I don't want to hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> every time to compile the changed class.

I read about the EclipseModel plugin but this does not seem to work (anymore) as can be read in the comments on the plugin's page: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=3822

I also tried the "*Make project automatically*" but this compiles ALL classes and not only the changed class. This is only not more time consuming it will also cause JRebel to reload all classes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In addition to Anton's answer check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12744437/104891) explaining why automatic compilation is disabled when there is an active run configuration. See also the [explanation from the developer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5473042) in the forum.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up creating a Macro which does the Save and the Make Build.
I then assigned the Ctrl+S shortcut to this Macro and then it works fine.

Comment: How, please give details :)

Comment: @AamirAfridi You need to record a macro for the two actions (File -> Save All and Build -> Make Project) as explain here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/recording-macros.html and then you need to assign the CTRL + S keyboard shortcut to that macro as explain here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/binding-macros-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html (When prompted for conflict just press "Remove" button to deassign the CTRL + S shortcut from the previous action)

Comment: @MnemonicFlow hahah you replied after like 2 years. Yes I figured that out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

What if you just remap the keys from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>? Basically you will just keep up with the habit of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> since you do that in Eclipse - just a matter of pressing a different key in IntelliJ.

IntelliJ IDEA 12 indeed comes with out-of-process compiler which compiles the project classes automatically, but it seems to be unpredictable - you might refresh the page and the class is not yet compiled. So in the scenario with JRebel the off-process compilation is no use, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. As soon as I add Ctrl+S keymapping to Make Project, Ctrl+S does not do anything anymore, not even saving the file itself. When I remove the keymapping Ctrl+S does at least work for saving again.

Comment: I did some further testing and the Ctrl+S seems to work for saving, but not for Make Project. Does IntelliJ support having 1 shortcut (Ctrl+S) for multiple Actions (Save All + Make Project)?

Comment: Normally I wouldn't use Ctrl+S in IntelliJ at - it saves files automatically for me. One option could be also to create a simple plugin that intercepts the Save action (http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2011/04/code-snippet-intercepting-on-save.html) and invokes the compier. But in general, I found that trying to adopt the habits that come from Eclipse to the new environment doesn't really make sense - it will only take you some days to get used to pressing Ctrl+F9 instead for Ctrl+S. After a while you'll be doing totally OK without Ctrl+S

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you want but normally I leave auto-save on, and when I need to compile the current class I'm working on, I just do `Ctrl + Shift + F9.`

Comment: Ctrl + F9 => [Make project]
Ctrl + Shift + F9 => [Compile selected file, package or module]
see https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 2):

My IntelliJ IDEA version is 2017.3.4, and I modified some values so that it compiles automatically.

[image: Settings]

[image: Registry]