# Reloading is not working in grails3.2.9

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I had to restart for every single change in the grails controller. It is showing the message "So and So File" groovy changed, recompiling... but not effecting to the application. How to resolve it

Current Stack
grails 3.2.9
Groovy 2.4.10
Java 8.0.25
IntelliJ 15

Answer (score 0):

I "kinda fixed" the problem by starting an extra daemon

> gradlew -t classes

see [Grails 3.2.11 not reloading controllers in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787026/grails-3-2-11-not-reloading-controllers-in-development)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated how you are launching the app but I expect you may be using a run config in the IDE that is not disabling the bytecode verifier.  The bytecode verifier must be disabled for reloading to work.  You can do that with `-noverify`.