# What is the difference between Grails 3.3.3 and 3.3.4?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

According to the [Grails project homepage](http://grails.org/download.html) version 3.3.4 is the latest release of Grails.

There are [release notes](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v3.3.4) for this release too but the refer to a GitHub [milestone](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/milestone/202) that contains no issues.

Does anyone know what in this latest release?

Comment: starting from 3.3.3 the dev auto update doesn't work, so I don't care much about those versions

Comment: @injecteer Your comment is mostly unrelated to the question here but I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have ver 3.3.2 now, and if I change something in a controller action, like add 'println' then I    see the change, unlike in 3.3.3+

Comment: @injecteer I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @injecteer See http://jeffscreencasts.s3.amazonaws.com/injecteer.mp4.

Comment: @injecteer If there is some circumstance for which the reloading agent doesn't work but it did work in 3.3.2, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues with details.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I had a similar issue before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787026/grails-3-2-11-not-reloading-controllers-in-development

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I upgraded to 3.3.5 and reloading works again!

Comment: @injecteer I don't know why it wasn't working for you before but I am glad it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change appears to be in how request params are included when redirecting:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/compare/v3.3.3...v3.3.4

Original params are no longer included when redirecting from a controller action.

It's odd that there was no issue linked for that though!

Summarizing for simplicity per comments below with Jeff: nothing is actually fixed in 3.3.4.  There were changes to fix one particular issue but they did not work and will instead be included as a fix in 3.3.5.

Comment: "It's odd that there was no issue linked for that though!" - there is an issue linked for that.

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/milestone/202?closed=1 shows issues closed in 3.3.4.  Linked from: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v3.3.4 Am I missing one?  I do use these when deciding when to upgrade so if I'm not seeing the right links, I'd love to know where they are!

Comment: Daniel - the reason the issue doesn't show up there is it was re-opened because it isn't fixed in 3.3.4 as was originally thought.  It has been moved to 3.3.5.  The issue is linked in the commit message that is included in the list of commits you will see at the link described in the answer above.

Comment: The issue is https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10965 and that is linked from the commit message at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/aae76f4b58b30352ad4431f2b42bb29a1804b66f.

Comment: Yep, I missed that.  Thanks for the link!  Is there any particular reason that's not in the release notes/closed issues/etc. for 3.3.4?  I would have completely overlooked that if not for this question and your comments.

Comment: " Is there any particular reason that's not in the release notes/closed issues/etc. for 3.3.4?" - Yes.  It isn't fixed in 3.3.4.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, it isn't fixed in 3.3.4 as was originally thought. It has been moved to 3.3.5.

Comment: Well that explains the confusion then!  Thanks again for clarifying.