# Trouble using IntelliJ with GWT

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, jrebel

I am currently using IntelliJ IDE for complex GWT project. I wanted to take advantage of JRebel in developement mode of GWT so recently I installed JRebel plugin for IntelliJ and am having trouble making it to work.

Basically IntelliJ does not have ability to auto-compile the application on change, so whenever you make changes to the code I have to go build -> compile to update the underlying .class file. Problem here is that I get error below whenever I perform this. In order to take advantage of JRebel I need to update .class file. Does anyone know how to make this work?

> Information:Using javac 1.7.0_21 to compile java sources
>   Information:15 errors Information:0 warnings Information:Compilation
>   completed with 15 errors and 0 warnings in 9 min 5 sec Error:GWT
>   Compiler: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
>   heap space Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.grow(ObjectInputStream.java:3462)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectInputStream.java:3269)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1787)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: at
>   java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733) Error:GWT Compiler:
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   Error:GWT Compiler: a

Comment: Hi. What is your jvm heap size (Xmx, Xms, MaxPermSize) ? Do you use any specific Jrebel config options ?

Comment: My vm args are: -Xss1024k, -Xms1024M, -Xmx2048M, -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M and I use default config option.

Comment: You are using the internal server of GWT dev mode or an external one ?

Comment: What do you mean by internal/external server? I use IntelliJ's run option with codeserver parameter.

Comment: GWT dev mode has an embedded jetty server. If you are just using the GWT configuration run then you are using the embedded jetty server :)    The build -> compile seems to do a compilation of your GWT module. This is not needed since you are in GWT dev mode. Try to check "Update resources on frame deactivation" in your run configuration. It will update the .class when you switch to your browser.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however .class file did not change when I modified the .java file. I need to update .class file while dev mode is running whenever file changes just like Eclipse. So JRebel know to swap the file.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you have the "build automatically" feature. For Intellij go to Settings > Compiler > "Make project automatically".

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744437/1722236) has more details about it.

Comment: "Make projet automatically" only works while not running / debugging so it won't work with JRebel/GWT dev mode since you are running.  But you can use the option "Update resources on frame deactivation" in the run configuration.

Comment: Exactly, I need to auto update .class whenever it changes while running the app in dev mode.