# Get IntelliJ to show compilation problems automatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, ide

In Eclipse if I make a compile-time breaking change to a low level library, it propagates through the rest of my open projects very promptly. I can then go through the breaks one by one and get my code to compile again.

In IntelliJ this seems like a hassle. I must manually compile each module. For reasons I do not yet understand making the module doesn't work; it must be compiled, and as such I must compile each module individually. (Eclipse has a "Refresh" option that can be applied to multiple projects at once). Worse, I have no indication that I have an outstanding error until I actually build my project in Maven.

Is there a way to expedite this and get my old workflow back?

Also, I'm still trying to improve my navigation of problems across modules but haven't really found a good keyboard-only way to do this.

Comment: Wow.  Every time ***I've*** so much as sneezed on an open file, IntelliJ will recompile *everything*.  Let me see if I can find the configuration I'm using for that so you could use it, too.

Comment: Your bounty was too tempting so I started my frenetic search to solve your issue, but... sigh... unfortunately for me it already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12744437/2164109 such question is updated for version 12, but checking in my IntelliJ IDE (v13) there are just minor differences, so it isn't worth a new answer...

Comment: @morgano discussing here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260058/1339987 my rec is post a simple duplicate answer linking, I'll award you then try to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open to toward the end of the bounty, since it's an expensive bounty I may as well find out if there's better ways to do it or anything else to learn.

Comment: @djechlin nah, don't worry about rewarding me, after all I'm also an ex-Eclipse user who also had the same concern when I switched to IntelliJ; I just didn't botter in investigate further. About your feature request in meta (I know, it was denied) you had a point: I didn't started looking for the answer until you put a bounty on it