# How to make intellij detect the errors proactively?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I develop with intellij (in java fyi), if I update for instance the return type of a method, I'm expecting intellij to mark all the files that are now not compiling without me doing a right-click compile.

I'm looking for such an option but I don't know where this is.

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744303/intellij-idea-java-classes-not-auto-compiling-on-save

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option 'out of the box'. IntelliJ just works different than, for example, Eclipse when it comes to compiling. Eclipse recompiles all files that are affected by a change as soon as you save your changes. In IntelliJ there are two ways of checking the effect of your changes:

1. Trigger the compilation explicitly with *Make Project* or the compile action *CTRL-SHIFT-F9*.
2. Open one of the affected classes: only then will IDEA's *Inspections* mechanism start checking it for errors.

The advantage is that you have less file system load while you are coding.

But as described in this answer, **there is a plugin** to achieve what you want (even though it seems to have some performance pitfalls): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744431/5788215

Comment: interesting ! I'll try this plugin and will see if my computer can smoothly accept the compiling effort.