# intellij run application does not start correctly

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I think I have a problem with my intellij run config. Everytime I make a change in my code and run my app with the intellij runner my code isn't built again and my changes are not visible.

after I run `mvn clean package install` everything works.

I have a standard java spring boot application, built with maven.

I know this is not much to base a possible answer on, but does anyone have an idea on what I could try?

*edit*
Intellij auto build is enabled

I think it has something to do with the fact that I have several seperate modules in 1 intellij open. If I open one module at once intellij automatically rebuilds correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744303/intellij-idea-java-classes-not-auto-compiling-on-save

Comment: let me know if your problem is solved with @shmosel comment >

Comment: If you use spring boot plugin for maven, you can also build and launch the app via `mvn spring-boot:run` target.

Comment: @AmitK: no, in my edit I tried to explain the issue