# Is there a way to automatically compile using maven after code changes when using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When using intelliJ, is there a way to automatically run maven compile after code changes? running mvn compile is too tedious each time.

Comment: Please provide more information. When would you like to compile the code? While the application is running?

Comment: [Use file watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA Java classes not auto compiling on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744303/intellij-idea-java-classes-not-auto-compiling-on-save)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Access Settings (Preferences on macOS). Select Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler.
2. Enable Build project automatically. Press OK.
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+A (Cmd+Shift+A on macOS) and search for Registry. Open it to find and enable compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running (IntelliJ IDEA 15 and newer).

Source:
https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/intellij/enable-automatic-compilation-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: This option is no longer available in the registry. I am trying to get my tests to auto compile under Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JRebel Plugin. If you are working with web apps its great.

Comment: jrebel is about deployment, not about compiling