# IntelliJ IDEA (2020.2): Gradle: The cache entry for initialization script 'ijinit.gradle' appears to be corrupted

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am working with Intellij Idea (CE)

- 2020.2.3

And using Gradle 6.7

I have the following situation:

- [IntelliJ IDEA (2020.2): Gradle: The cache entry for initialization script (appears to be corrupted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823486/intellij-idea-2020-2-gradle-the-cache-entry-for-initialization-script-appea)

Part of the solution is disable the `Android` plugin (I don't work with Android - so is fine for me).

But until now each time I start the IDE - it automatically builds the `spring-framework` project based on Gradle - therefore it starts the daemon and tries to build. But I receive the following error message:

[image]

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The cache entry for initialization script 'C:\Users\mjord\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' appears to be corrupted.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 149ms
```

I can confirm the `ijinit.gradle` file exists

[image]

but - why should be corrupted?

The Gradle configuration is as follows:

[image]

From above:

**Notes**

- Is used a custom *gradle home*
- Is used a custom *user gradle home* (repository)

Apart:

- In the PC/Laptop the `.gradle` directory located within the *username* directory is empty

I did a research in SO about this, but the most similar situation that appears is about the `dependency cache` corruption scenario, such as:

- [Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network)

Where the solutions suggested are about to configure the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, but it does not exist in the original project and something about network issues (it does not apply in this case)

How fix this situation?

Comment: What is the content of `ijinit.gradle` file? Does it help to use different Gradle version? Try different local installation or switch to wrapper.properties: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper

Comment: There could be an issue caused by antivirus/firewall corrupting the IDE caches and the file from which Gradle daemon is initized.