# IntelliJ IDEA (2020.2): Gradle: Lock file: repository/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am working with Intellij Idea (CE)

- 2020.2.3

And using Gradle 6.7

#### Path Variables

Where in the OS exists configured, the following about Path Variables in the bash profile:

- GRADLE_HOME = /Users/username/.../gradle/6.7
- GRADLE_USER_HOME = /Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository

How you can see, customized locations

The `/Users/username/.gradle` directory is empty.

About Intellij Idea, its configuration for Gradle is as follows:

[image]

Same paths as the bash profile.

#### Note

The following figures that represents the interaction with the IDE, are based on:

- `/Users/username/.gradle` directory empty
- `/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository` directory empty
- Working with `spring-framework` project based on `Gradle`

It to have a quick discard something around there.

Ok, startup process:

[image]

[image]

Starts to *Sync*

[image]

A Gradle's daemon is started

[image]

After of some seconds fails with:

[image]

The error message is:

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
   > Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: unknown
     Our PID: 713
     Owner Operation: unknown
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: /Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The `repository` directory shows the following

[image]

The `/Users/username/.gradle` directory shows

[image]

**Observation:** Until this point observe in the two previous Figures that the `daemon/6.7` path/directory appears twice in the *repository* and `.gradle` directories respectively

**Note:** When the IDE is closed, just in that moment, in the `/Users/username/.gradle` directory appears this new file (`registry.bin.lock`) as follows:

[image]

I got this behavior even if I delete the `idea-directory-installation/.gradle` directory (**not** `/Users/username/.gradle` directory) and even with `Invalidating Caches/Restart`

What is missing, what to do?

Comment: Did you disable antivirus as I advised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64861388/intellij-idea-2020-2-gradle-the-cache-entry-for-initialization-script-ijini ?

Comment: Such problems happen when some other process locks the file. The could be problem with processes on your system cannot terminal(exit) properly and hanging locking the files. AV/firewall can cause such issues.

Comment: This case is for a Mac, there is no an antivirus, here behaves better than in Windows. About the lock file: when the error is thrown just then in the console/terminal I just execute `gradle --status` and shows nothing, if I execute the same command when the IDE is building just show one daemon. Not sure what is happening

Comment: Once I got resolved this scenario in Mac, I am going to return to Windows.

Comment: It could be that some another process locks the file. Use `lsof` to check this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22265/362450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this **specific** and **explicit** situation, the problem is about that the secondary storage (pendrive) does **not** have the same *format type* as the main storage (Hard Disk - HDD/SSD), for more information follow in order the following links:

- [Clarify in the docs what filesystem types are supported #17932](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17932)
- [File locking fails on ExFAT SD card #4329](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4329)
- [Supported File Systems](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/file_system_watching.html#supported_file_systems)

Therefore as summary:

**Scenario**

Exists a Secondary Drive that is used how *repository* for Gradle

**Solution**

Format the secondary device with the same *format type* as the main hard disk has and problem solved!. I am not sure why this situation or behavior. Otherwise an error message about a `.lock` file exists arises and the daemon remains hanged

**Consideration**

I had this situation in 2 PC and the format types for each OS is different. Therefore this solution was applied to them and worked, macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for other running Gradle processes and terminate them. In any system's shell put the following command:

```
ps aux | grep gradle
```

Then, kill the previously found Gradle processes using their pid (process identifier). For instance, if the found Gradle process has the pid 12345, the command would be this one:

```
kill -9 12345
```